# API to create send-able data extension with SendableDataExtensionField not allow SubscriberID?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to pass SubscirberID field and set as the SendableDataExtensionField but is not working. The doc for Fuel SDK say you can only use _SubscriberKey or EmailAddress.

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extensions/data-extension-create.html

I am not using Fuel but assuming it is the same. I want to have a field SubscriberID and relate it to the SubscriberID field on ET.

I saw this post here and I get a similar error "The SendableSubscriberField field cannot be blank.".

[Fuel SDK + PHP + Sendable Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33999/fuel-sdk-php-sendable-data-extension)

I can see it is looking for SubscriberKey in the soap but I do want to use SubscriberID. Any ideas or anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not in docs but I saw the pattern was "Email Adress", "Subscriber Key". So I tried "Subscriber ID" with the space in between and that worked.