# Create Sendable Data Extension using FuelSDK (C#)

Tags: fuel-sdk, c#, dataextensions

I have read and tried unsuccessfully the solutions in the two other posts regarding this subject, which appear to be focused on PHP.
[Create Sendable Data Extension using FuelSDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/create-sendable-data-extension-using-fuelsdk?s=1|2.7282) and
[Fuel SDK + PHP + Sendable Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33999/fuel-sdk-php-sendable-data-extension?newreg=12e4d729ad8f4e8d8ba5a7e61daf066d)

Is it possible to create a sendable data extension via the c# fuel sdk? When I supply the .SendableDataExtensionField, I get an XML serialization error.

```
ET_DataExtension postDataExtension = new ET_DataExtension(); 
postDataExtension.AuthStub = myclient; 
postDataExtension.CustomerKey = NameOfTestDataExtension;
postDataExtension.IsSendableSpecified = true; 
postDataExtension.IsSendable = true; 
postDataExtension.SendableDataExtensionField = new DataExtensionField() { Name = "EmailAddress" };
ET_DataExtensionColumn colEmail = new ET_DataExtensionColumn() { Name = "EmailAddress", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text, IsPrimaryKey = true, MaxLength = 100, IsRequired = true };
ET_DataExtensionColumn col1 = new ET_DataExtensionColumn() { Name = "Last Name", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text }; 
ET_DataExtensionColumn col2 = new ET_DataExtensionColumn() { Name = "First Name", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text }; 
postDataExtension.Columns = new ET_DataExtensionColumn[] { colEmail, col1, col2 };
```

> "The type FuelSDK.ET_DataExtensionColumn was not expected. Use the
>   XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not
>   known statically."

I get a similar error about Attribute when I specify the SendableSubscriberField attribute.

Any input/direction/resources much appreciated. I've spent the last 2 days in the sdk documentation without success.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old; but I ran into the same issue and thought it might prove helpful for others.

Your setting the SendableDataExtensionField to what is likely a raw FuelSDK.SendableSubscriberField.  You can set this to the ET_DataExtensionColumn instance for your email address instead (i.e. colEmail in the example above.)

Similarly; for the SendableSubscriberField you should use an ET_ProfileAttribute with the name set to either "Email Address" or "Subscriber Key" based on your salesforce configuration.

Good luck!

Comment: can you please elaborate on this for me? I am having the same issue... :(

Comment: This is the correct answer: 
Code:
IsSendable = true,
                IsSendableSpecified = true,
                SendableDataExtensionField = emailColumn,
                SendableSubscriberField = new FuelSDK.ET_ProfileAttribute{ Name = "Subscriber Key" },