# How to set SendableSubscriberField value while creating sendable Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, node.js

What value should I use for `SendableSubscriberField` field?
I have seen some answers. Which is suggesting, we can set either `Email Address` or `Subscriber Key` based on your salesforce configuration?

How can I determine, which `SendableSubscriberField` is enabled in my salesforce configuration?

While I pass `Subscriber Key` in `SendableSubscriberField` salesforce throws the following error:

`The SendableSubscriberField cannot be SubscriberKey because the SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has not been turned on.`

So, How to check SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has been turned on using SOAP API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough about the Subscriber Key business rule status, meaning you will need to log a case with Marketing Cloud Support and request Subscriber Key to be enabled in case you need it.

As for which value to use between Email Address and Subscriber Key, it depends if you are using Subscriber Key, so by current configuration - since it's not enabled you can only go with the `Email Address`.

Should probably look something like this:

```
"SendableDataExtensionField": {"Name": "CustomerID"}, "SendableSubscriberField": {"Name":"Email Address"}
```

- [Sendable Data Extension with Fuel SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/create-sendable-data-extension-using-fuelsdk)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There is any way to check SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has been turned on or off before creating Data extension.If I find out this then I will use `Subscriber Key` when the SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has been turned on else `Email Address`.

Comment: You can check if Subscriber Key has been turned on by asking Support or your MC account executive, though I think you should see it in UI, via Email Studio - All Subscribers list as well. If you see this column and are able to search by it. Plus if you create Data Extension manually then you also have this option in UI to define which field to use as Subscriber Key.

In case it's not enabled and you will be requesting it, here's a quick reference on how to get started > https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_migrate_your_account_to_use_the_subscriber_key_feature.htm&type=5

Comment: Is there any way to check SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has been turned on or off using SOAP API?

Comment: Not directly. The message you got about about 'SendableSubscriberField' directly states that it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my problem is that SendableSubscriberField varies MC account wise. Some account has it Email Address, Subscriber Key some account may have the different one. How can I determine it dynamically for logged in account user? There is any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [here](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/blob/91b78ffa03af4de30a9fd6964034f8dbc57a2900/src/test/java/com/exacttarget/fuelsdk/ETDataExtensionTest.java#L1972) 
Test case from 71 to 74 are coded for Sendable Data Extension.
Hope it will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my problem is that `SendableSubscriberField` varies MC account wise. Some account has it `Email Address`, `Subscriber Key` some account may have the different one.  How can I determine it dynamically for logged in account user? There is any way to get this?